# VBA: How to pull "Product" down x number of rows

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to be able to have a cell that shows the product of the range of rows set by a number of cells. For example, if in cell `A1` I have the number 10, and my product range begins in `A2`, I'd like to be able to calculate `PRODUCT(A2:A12);` but, if I change `A1` to `20`, the product now pulls `PRODUCT(A2:A22)`

I've tried some various for and while loops but I'm pretty new to VBA syntax

Code I tried:

```
Sub ReturnsProduct()
    Dim StartNumber As Single
    Dim i As Integer
    i = Worksheets("Annual Growth").Range("I7")
    Dim cell
    cell = Worksheets("Annual Growth").Range("C12", "C100")
    For cell = 1 To i
    WorksheetFunction.Product (Worksheets("Annual Growth").Range("E12"))
    Next
    Worksheets("Annual Growth").Range("G9").Value = Result
    End Sub
```

Comment: `=PRODUCT($A$2:INDEX($A:$A,A1))`

Comment: Using the ranges in your code: `=PRODUCT($C$12:INDEX($C:$C,$I$7)+ROW($C$12)-1)`

Comment: Thank you so much!